# Restart a conversation in Dialogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Hello stack overflow community,

I would like your help in the following problem:

Currently I am running a Dialogflow chatbot that has some intents and gives back some responses. The chat bot works perfectly until now. For your information, I use webhook to get back responses.

Here is a screenshot of my intents flow: [dialogflow chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUiC5.png)

What I struggle to do is to give the user the opportunity to rerun the whole conversation from the start. Do you know how can I achieve this in Dialogflow?

Python code snippet to run webhook:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# default route

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'Chatbot is online and running!'

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def webhook():

# return response

    req = request.get_json(force=True, silent = True)

    action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')

    intent_name = req.get('queryResult').get('intent').get('displayName')

    if action == "get_results" and intent_name == 'KellyMovieBot':

        return make_response(jsonify(suggest_movie(req)))

    elif action == "ask_question" and intent_name == 'ask_first_time':

        return make_response(jsonify(propose_second_movie(req)))

    elif action == "thanks_giving_end" and intent_name == "thanks_giving":

        return make_response(jsonify(thanks(req)))

    elif action == "rerun_conversation" and intent_name == "rerun_conversation":

        user_answer = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters').get('user_answer')

        if user_answer == "No" or user_answer == "no":

            return {'fulfillmentText': "Enjoy your film!"}

        elif user_answer == "Yes" or user_answer == "yes":

            return {'fulfillmentText': "Let's start again..."}

# run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Note:** The functions suggest_movie(), propose_second_movie(), thanks() are three functions that have been created in order to return 3 different outputs based on the communication flow.

What I want is find the correct syntax that will allow me to **RERUN** the whole conversation again if the user says 'Yes' else Dialogflow should end the conversation.

I would appreciate any help or advise you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by sending a follow-up event rather than a response.  In this case when the user responds with yes, in your code, you'd return:

```
{
   "followupEventInput": {
        "name": "KellyMovieBot",
   "languageCode": "en-US"
   }
}
```

Make sure your KellyMovieBot intent has the same event name.  You don't have to use the specified value, but the event name as sent in the response should also match the event name as configured on the intent.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom#invoke_event_from_webhook